# Looking for examples to immer produce with the ngrx 8

Tags: angular, typescript, immer.js

Looked around the web and can't find an example of using 
`import produce, {Draft} from "immer";`
with the ngrx `on()` 
the closest I can find is:
a non complete solution on:
https://github.com/immerjs/immer/issues/252

```
import produce, { Draft } from 'immer';
import { ActionCreator, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ActionType, FunctionWithParametersType } from '@ngrx/store/src/models';

function produceOn<Type extends string, C extends FunctionWithParametersType<any, object>, State>(
  actionType: ActionCreator<Type, C>,
  callback: (draft: Draft<State>, action: ActionType<ActionCreator<Type, C>>) => any,
) {
  return on(actionType, (state: State, action): State => produce(state, (draft) => callback(draft, action)));
}

// Usage:

const featureReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  produceOn(action, (draft, action) => {
     // TODO STUFF
  }
);

export function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  return featureReducer(state, action);
}
```

not sure how to incoperate the on() with immer with ngrx 8

Sean.

Answer (score 11):

found the answer:

```
import {createReducer} from '@ngrx/store';
import {on} from "@ngrx/store";
import produce, {Draft} from "immer";

export const initialUserState: IUserState = {
    knownUsers: [user1, user2],
    selectedUser: null,
    scenes: null
};

export function produceOn<Type extends string, C extends FunctionWithParametersType<any, object>, State>(
    actionType: ActionCreator<Type, C>,
    callback: (draft: Draft<State>, action: ActionType<ActionCreator<Type, C>>) => any,
) {return on(actionType, (state: State, action): State => produce(state, (draft) => callback(draft, action)));}

export const loadRequest = createAction('[Scenes API] Scene Load Request', props<{ businessId: BusinessId }>());
export const loadSuccess = createAction('[Scenes API] Scene Load Success', props<{ scenes: List<SceneModel> }>());

// ngrx 8+ with immer and support for on() within reducer

const featureReducer = createReducer(
    initialUserState,
    produceOn(loadSuccess, (draft, action) => {
        draft.scenes = {myList: [1,2,3]};
    }),
    produceOn(loadFailure, (draft, action) => {
        draft.scenes = {myList: []};
        console.log('error loading...');
    })
);
```

Comment: just posting a link to your discussion on immer's github as it's relevant to people here and theres no link through: https://github.com/immerjs/immer/issues/252

Notably, the last comment, ngrx-etc library is built with immer and gives essentially your method.
https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-etc

Answer (score 7):

There is an repo from a ngrx-maintainer
https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-etc
which gives you a mutableOn function, which can be used like here

```
mutableOn(increment, (state, {incrementBy}) => {
  state.count += incrementBy;
})
```

Comment: tried to use it and got lots of TS errors so opted out.

Comment: can you elaborate on which errors there were? typing should be correct as far as I see